# How do I resolve this HTTP API call error, code": 404, "message": "Invalid delegate"?

Tags: api, http, delegates

I've created a workflow in Tray.io which uses a Service account and an Admin account via the use of JWT token and Access Token to list delegates of a mailbox, loop through the list, add them into a AD group which gets created as a Google group via directory sync and then remove them as a delegate to the mailbox. Once the list is complete the group email is then added as a delegate to the mailbox sometimes this completes without any errors but at times it will fail/attempt to retry as it keeps throwing the following error:

```
"response": {
        "error": {
            "code": 404,
            "message": "Invalid delegate",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "Invalid delegate",
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "notFound"
                }
            ],
            "status": "NOT_FOUND"
        }
    },
    "message": "API error"
```

However, if I stop the automation, log in as the mailbox and then manually delegate the Google Group access it succeeds.

I tried delaying (up to 5 minutes) the addition of the group as a delegate from the flow - same error
I tried running a fresh workflow just to add the email of the group as a delegate - same error
I did a GET call for the group and was able to confirm that the group exists with a email address and then re-attempted to add the group as a delegate - same error.

When I use the Graph Explorer I can add the email as a delegate but if I try and use curl or http using other platforms I receive the error until after a good 5-10 minutes before it accepts.
I can also immediately do it from the mailboxes account settings so I don't think propagation is the issue.

As mentioned, this is hit and miss, sometimes it works flawlessly, but there are times when it takes 10+ minutes until it succeeds.